# Night transport from Paris CDG airport to downtown -- ticket and price?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, night-transport

The last RER train from Aeroport Charles-de-Gaulle leaves at 23h48. Then there're **night buses** (**Noctilien**) leaving twice an hour to Gare du Nord. I was able to find that on the website http://www.ratp.fr .

However, I didn't find which ticket (and at which price) I need for that. So that's basically my question. As well, if there are other reasonable options for getting downtown, they would be interesting for me as well of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.aeroportsdeparis.fr/ADP/fr-FR/Passagers/Acces-Plans-Parking/Paris-CDG/Acces/Transports-En-Commun/paris_charles_gaulle_noctilien.htm) (and [here](http://www.transilien.com/static/plans-reseau/aeroport-roissy)) states that the ticket price for the Noctilien is 7,60 € and that you can buy directly on board. Note that this is the equivalent of 4 T+ tickets, so if you're planning on moving around a lot in Paris, you could just buy a *carnet* of 10 directly (27% cheaper), though I'm not sure whether you can buy them directly in the airport - that's probably worth a separate question.

Comment: The first link is perfect, thanks! I would only add: The prices of tickets in Paris increase from time to time (so it might be more than €7.6 in some time), but it seems that the _"equivalent of 4 t+"_ is a stable thing, no matter the price.